# Configure webcam

Tags: kernel, skype, webcam, cheese

I see a garbled image when using my web cam using Cheese or Skype using uvcvideo kernel module. I am aware that this is a known bug, but does it have a solution yet?

Links: [Kernel modules with problems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam/Troubleshooting), [uvcvideo bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cheese/+bug/290506)

I have no problems with VLC of guvcvideo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem solved. This is how I solved the problem with:

**1.Cheese**

The bug with Cheese has been eliminated by changing the resolution to 1280 x 720 in Cheese Preferences. Check the screen shot below.

[image: Cheese Preferences]

**2. Skype**

There should be a skype configuration file in your home directory:

```
~/.Skype/YourUserName/config.xml
```

(Replace YourUserName with your skype user name). Open this file with a text editor, search for the **Video** tag and change it:

```
<Video>
<CaptureHeight>720</CaptureHeight>
<CaptureWidth>1280</CaptureWidth>
</Video>
```